# Did Joe Biden mumble/stutter after saying "America is a nation that can be defined in a single word"?

Tags: united-states, joe-biden

In a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvA-Vf0MomM&ab_channel=HindustanTimes) of the Hindustan Times, Joe Biden seems to be saying:

> America is a nation that can be defined in a single word: Asufutimaehaehfutbw

I can't help but wonder if it is a fake.

US Representative [Troy Nehls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_Nehls) has [used](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/KYzks9Q6hyI) this footage in a house hearing, questioning his mental health, but the latest [Health Report](https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Health-Summary-2.16.pdf) of Joe Biden says that he is…

> …a healthy, vigorous, 80-year old male, who is fit to successfully execute the duties of the Presidency, to include those as Chief Executive, Head of State and Commander in Chief.

So, did Joe Biden mutter nonsense after saying those words?

Comment: Does anyone have a link that continues the speech, without truncating it at that point? It just looks like a fix. There are any number of reasons for distortion from a microphone, and the video itself is distorted too: very low quality. We barely notice the artifacts in a digital compressed video, but similar can happen with sound.

Comment: I saw this reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/Ask_Politics/s/FTb0aBMowP

Answer (score 51, accepted):

President Biden answers the (self-asked) question by starting an anecdote about talking to Xi Jinping on the subject. He briefly gets tongued-tied while trying to say "I was in the foothills of the Himalayas", but goes on to finish the story and give the word "possibilities" as the answer to the question.

[Original footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3UiJrfGYMs&t=12s)

The White House provided a [transcript of the speech](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/speeches-remarks/2022/04/08/remarks-by-president-biden-vice-president-harris-and-judge-ketanji-brown-jackson-on-the-senates-historic-bipartisan-confirmation-of-judge-jackson-to-be-an-associate-justice-of-the-supreme-court/):

> And, folks — (applause) — let me close with what I’ve long said: America is a nation that can be defined in a single word.  I was in the foothi- — foot- — excuse me, in the foothills of the Himalayas with Xi Jinping, traveling with him.  (Inaudible) traveled 17,000 miles when I was Vice President at the time.  I don’t know that for a fact.
>
> And we were sitting alone.  I had an interpreter and he had an interpreter.  And he looked at me.  In all seriousness, he said, “Can you define America for me?”  And I said what many of you heard me say for a long time.  I said, “Yes, I can, in one word: possibilities.”  (Applause.)  “Possibilities.”  That, in America, everyone should be able to go as far as their hard work and God-given talent will take them.  And possibilities.  We’re the only ones.  That’s why we’re viewed as the “ugly Americans”: We think anything is possible.  (Laughter.)

[Newsweek](https://www.newsweek.com/joe-biden-viral-tiktok-america-xi-jinping-comments-1825039) gives background about how one of his political opponents, Repubican Troy Nehls, capitalised on this flub in a 2022 House hearing.

Joe Biden has [spoken](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2020/01/joe-biden-stutter-profile/602401/) [before](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWn1CkIU_rc) about his stuttering condition and his struggle to overcome it.

Comment: Is this stuttering related to some recent illness / old age ailment - in his older speeches, when he was younger, stuttering doesn't seem to be present (at least from what I could make out).

Comment: @sfxedit: See the last link for his own story about how he has suffered since he was a child, overcomes it by preparing and not rushing, and explaining how it still recurs when he is tired.

Comment: @sfxedit - He makes absolutely no secret of this. He talked directly about it in one of the "town halls" when he was running for President, and there's [well-publicized story](https://www.cnn.com/2021/01/19/politics/brayden-harrington-biden-inauguration/index.html) about a young stutterer he befriended at one of his campaign event rope lines. Its really weird (and kinda gross) that people still get away with acting like his lifelong stutter is some sign of dementia.

Comment: Please stop leaving comments trying to diagnose mental acuity based on speech patterns and anecdotes where n=1 or n=2, that just happen to push your personal political barrow. The question is NOT "Is Biden old?", "Is Biden incoherent?", "Has Biden got worse?", 'Are the Democrats lying?" and we don't want to hear your take on those questions.

Comment: This answer is just *yes* plus unsolicited campaigning.

Comment: @Haukinger: Campaigning? I don't see that. I do not endorse Biden in the slightest. It restores the context that makes it clear that the mistake was not simply a gibberish utterance - there was an immediate clarification, and the video wasn't entirely fake.